# Using collection_select in Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for

I need a multiple selection choice in a Rails form to create a new Topic, when creating a new Topic users can select a Language from the drop-down menu.

Topic.rb

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :language
end
```

language.rb

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
end
```

How would I use the collection_select method to have a user select a language?

The topic DB has a `language` field.

The language DB has a `name` field which I want to display to the user and a `permalink` field which I want to be the value of the dropdown that is stored in the topic db.

Answer (score 0):

```
collection_select(:topic, :language_id, Language.all, :permalink, :name)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Collection Select**

My understanding is that `collection_select` is not dependent on your associations

According to the [Rails Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select), and based off our own experience, the `collection_select` functionality can work with "pure" data, like this:

```
<%= subscriber.collection_select(:subscriber_id, Subscriber.where(:user_id => current_user.id), :id, :name_with_email, include_blank: 'Subscribers') %>
```

---

**Selecting A Language**

In your case, there are several issues which need to be addressed

Firstly, your `foreign_key` needs to be corrected in the `topic` database:

> The topic DB has a language field

Your `topic` DB needs to reference `langugage_id`, like this:

> id | language_id | created_at | updated_at

Once this has been done, it means you can populate the `topics` db with the `language_id` required to make to make the relation work. I'd use this collection_select for this:

```
<%= form_for @topic do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:langauge_id, Language.all, :id, :name, include_blank: 'Languages') %>
<% end %>
```